# Functional Analysis: Operator Norm

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

Following scenario: I have a matrix (linear operator) $W: V \rightarrow X$, where $V$ and $X$ are normed spaces. I now have an expression of the form $\vert\vert W\left( v_1 - v_2\right)\vert\vert$, where $v_1$, $v_2 \in V$. I would like to make the approximation $$\vert\vert W\left( v_1 - v_2\right)\vert\vert \leq \vert\vert W\vert\vert_{\text{op}} \vert\vert v_1 - v_2\vert\vert, \qquad (\star)$$ where I denote by $\vert\vert \cdot\vert\vert_{\text{op}}$ the [operator norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm). Now, to the best of my knowledge, $(\star)$ only holds when we assume that $\vert\vert v_1 - v_2\vert\vert \leq 1$ because the operator norm is given by $$\vert\vert W\vert\vert_{\text{op}} = \sup_{v\in V}\left\{ \vert\vert Wv\vert\vert, \vert\vert v\vert\vert \leq 1 \right\}.$$

However, in the case that I would like to consider, it is not given that $\vert\vert v_1 - v_2\vert\vert \leq 1$.

**Question**: In this case, is there still a way to use the inequality that I made in $(\star)$? (I would be happy if this could also be explained or proven.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to call the linear map $T$. Let $v\in V$ be arbitrary. If $v=0$, then clearly $\|T(v)\|\leq \|T\|_{\text{op}}\cdot \|v\|$, because we even have equality. If $v\neq 0$, then consider the vector $\xi:=\frac{v}{\|v\|}$. This has unit norm, so by definition of operator norm as a supremum,
\begin{align}
\|T(\xi)\|\leq \|T\|_{\text{op}}.
\end{align}
Multiply throughout by $\|v\|$ to get
\begin{align}
\|T(v)\|\leq \|T\|_{\text{op}}\cdot \|v\|.
\end{align}
So, this inequality holds for all $v\in V$, regardless of their norm.